# The potential of two conjoined charged liquid spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

Two small charged liquid spheres with radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ are a distance $d$ apart. Both have some potential $U_1$ and $U_2$ relative to infinity. Some time later, they merge into one bigger liquid sphere because of the attractive force. What would be the electrical potential of the merged sphere relative to infinity?

I think I would use somehow the test charges, but generally I don't know what to do. I know I should show some attempt of the solution but I have no clue. Please give me some hint how to get started. I am confused slightly with that infinity.

Comment: How does the potential of an isolated sphere relate to the charge it holds?

Comment: Those spheres are just in some electrical field and both are conducting, so they have also its potentials, but no further information. But i think i know how to solve it right now. My English is limited so maybe I just expressed that badly.

Comment: Those spheres are so small we consider them as the point charges.

Comment: If they are point charges, why do they have radii? And how to you calculate the potential of a point charge?

Comment: Oh, I see, I combined two exercises, no, they are not the point charges.

Comment: I have attempted to rephrase the question so that it's a little easier to understand.  @Leif, if this isn't what you intended, then click on the "edit" link below your answer, select the original version, and save it.  (Or, better, edit it yourself and try to clarify what you mean.)